# Angular Service Is Not A Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a simple logging service in Angular:

```
app.service('$userInteraction', [function() {

  var userLog = "";

  this.log = function (datetime, screen, logMessage) {
    userLog.concat(datetime + "\t" + screen + " Screen\t" + logMessage + "\n");
  }

  this.getLog = function () {
    return userLog;
  }

  this.clearLog = function () {
    userLog = "";
  }

}]);
```

And I use it in one of my controllers like so:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$userInteraction', function($scope, $userInteraction) {

    $userInteraction.log(Date(), 'Login', 'Some random message.');

}]);
```

But when I run my code I get the following error:

> TypeError: $userInteraction.log is not a function

Though I could've sworn that it worked before. I'm fairly new to Angular so this might very well be a newbie mistake. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 20 views and no answer.. can't be something obvious then.

Comment: Actually your code is working on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ksrN2831Ss6tgFZS9hQY?p=preview). Could it be that your service is in a diffferent module and you forgot to declare that module as dependency?

Comment: @skubski - sorry that was actually just a copy-paste error when I typed out the question. Also, not in a different module. Like I said, I really thought this worked before and then it just randomly broke. Angular is freaking out.

Comment: @DeanGrobler It works. I do not see any error. Please see my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/13rBKqAO7kAfQvtDhjom?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

this question is old, but help someone... You code run on plunker, problably you have duplicate services name... Check all files angularjs and verify if exist another service with same name.

I had similar problem. Two services with same name and call did not have function called.